# How to change the MySql server's parameters in AWS's RDS-MySql server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I run an RDS instance in `AWS` and have a `MySql` server installed there. I want to change the parameters `net_read_timeout` and `net_write_timeout` to some bigger values from their respective default values.

I tried using the parameter setting window in the RDS console -

```
RDS ->
Parameter groups -> default.mysql8.0
```

, but failing as below

[image]

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then select this parameter group while creating a new database or if you have a database already, modify it & change its parameter group to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Parameter group and attach to your RDS instance. However, you can't change the parameter values in a default DB parameter group. Refer this:
[Modify Amazon RDS DB parameter group](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-modify-parameter-group-values/)